# Video freezes after 30 seconds opencv object detection

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I am doing a project using opencv. However, even for a simple code, the video works fine for about 30 seconds. Then it freezes and computer hangs. Is it the problem of the driver v4l or something. I want continuous streaming of video. My code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

flag = 1
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    _,img = capture.read()
    simg = cv2.blur(img, (5,5))
    simg = cv2.GaussianBlur(simg,(5,5),0)
    simg = cv2.medianBlur(simg,5)

    frame1 = cv2.rectangle(simg,(200,200),(400,400),(0,255,0))
    frame2 = simg[200:400,200:400]

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # define range of blue color in HSV
    lower_yellow = np.array([20,100,100])
    upper_yellow = np.array([30,255,255])

    # Threshold the HSV image to get only yellow colors
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_yellow, upper_yellow)


    img_mom = cv2.moments(mask,0)
    area = img_mom['m00']

    if((area > 800000) and flag==1):
        print 'found'
        flag=0
        print area

    cv2.imshow('2',simg)
    cv2.imshow('area',frame2)
    cv2.imshow('3',mask)
    k = cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

What should I do?

Comment: can u please tell the error that appears ? also try lower_yellow = np.array([20,100,100], dtype=np.uint8) and same dtype for upper_yellow

Comment: No error is shown. The computer just hangs. However at the beginning, an error is shown:
       HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L/V4L2: VIDIOC_S_CROP

Comment: Object detection happens smoothly before it hangs

Comment: works fine on my laptop, just made 2 edits:
lower_yellow = np.array([20,100,100], dtype=np.uint8)
upper_yellow = np.array([30,255,255], dtype=np.uint8)
and i am able to detect yellow object quite nicely !

Comment: I am able to detect yellow object. But after some 30 to 40 seconds, video freezes and laptop hangs. Does this have anything to do with the driver?

Comment: If possible, help me here also:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21079913/finding-width-of-colored-object-opencv-python

Comment: If u are working on ubuntu-linux type gstreamer-properties in terminal an check the settings also see [http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1455700](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1455700) your HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L/V4L2: VIDIOC_S_CROP error is dicussed here !